# What is the use of development.log file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

What is the use of Development.log file that is present in log folder of the rails application. I see that as the time goes on the size of this file increases . Right now in my application its size is 14gb. Will it affect the performance of the application? if so what should be done prevent that ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

All the informations about your web applications requests are written in it, and it is quite useful.

When you start your application with `rails s` you can see it (it is tailing the development.log)

Since its the development.log, you can clean the content, but be sure to leave it there so you can see what your application is doing.

Answer (score 0):

As for your second question. It will affect your whole server, if the size increases and consume space on your hdd. Consider deleting or gziping them from time to time.
P.S.: I don't know for certain if in production the log size are handled automatically.